# State of GPU support (Asus GL552VW with NVidia 960M)

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-gnome, gpu

So recently i'm trying to switch from Windows to Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. And i'm running into GPU problems using a laptop with a 960M (Asus GL552VW). One of these was that it froze when booting if i didn't set nouveau.modeset=0. I'm using the NVidia 381 driver now and that solved the problem.

However i'm still left with these problems, which i know others have as well. But their solutions haven't fixed it for me yet, nor did several different reinstalls. I'm having similar issues with default Ubuntu as well, both 16.04 and 17.04:

1. GRUB shows a grey screen.
2. Screen turns on and off / Black when login in.
3. Excessive screen tearing / v-sync related issues.
4. Switching to the Nouveau driver causes a freeze at the splash screen at login.

Of course anyone able to directly point me to the root causes of any of these problems is much appreciated. Regardless i'm going to keep looking into them to fix them.

But what i'm really looking for is someone to give it to me straight what the state of all this is? I'm not expecting gaming performance like on a Windows machine. Driver / Game optimizations obviously matter. But i do want a smooth desktop experience. Is this even achievable? Or is the GPU support just not quite there yet? Or should I maybe look into using the Intel HD graphics 530 integraded GPU (i do prefer to use my machine to the fullest)?

Comment: If you don't need the graphics horsepower, you should just outright disable the Nvidia card and use the Intel one

Comment: It's kind of a waste to not use the Geforce imo. Also the intel GPU also gives me problem number #4 as well.

Comment: Anyway I've been trying tonight.

Problem 1: This is probably the case because i only have 1 OS installed and it's not properly displaying some kind of background. By holding shift during boot i can still boot into grub and start with nouveau.modeset=0.

Problem 2 and 3: Been trying a lot. But i cannot seem to fix any of these issues. Other then booting with nouveau.modeset=0.

I'm still hoping someone will shed some light on all of this. Right now I'm definitely starting to lean towards the drivers just not being that good...